# Is there an adjective that means "elsewhere"?

Tags: word-request, adjectives, adverbs

Let's say we have an example:

> Sorry, I just meant something I observe in **elsewhere** discussions, not in our past topics

Since [elsewhere](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/elsewhere) is an adverb, not adjective, the example is ungrammatical. "Other discussions" can be an alternative, but I want to emphasize that those discussions can only be found in unrelated contexts, like in another forums or platforms. "I observe in somewhere else" is good, but I'd like to find an adjective for it. Do you know any?

Comment: Most people would just say "other discussions".

Comment: I want to emphasize it's "elsewhere". "Other" can mean that it's in the current forum

Comment: "discussions in other forums". Sometimes it's easier just to add other qualifiers.

Comment: actually I just want to broaden my vocabulary, so I specifically wants to know an adjective for this. If it's just about getting it done, I think I can do it

Comment: Sometimes there just isn't such a word.

Answer (score 2):

Your example makes better use of "other":

> Sorry, I just meant something I observe in **other** discussions, not in our past topics

But in other contexts, you can use other adjectives. See below:

> In the **different** discussions that I had, I noticed...
>
> During the **various** discussions in the past...

You may even use "elsewhere", but with a different word order (and different meaning):

> I noticed **elsewhere** in discussions ...

or

> I noticed in discussions **elsewhere** ...

Comment: "Other discussions" can be an alternative, but I want to emphasize that those discussions can only be found in unrelated contexts, like in another forums or platforms

Comment: What is wrong with @virolino 's 'I noticed in discussions elsewhere'? That is what I would say (as native BrE speaker). It is quite irrelevant that the word 'elsewhere' might have been described as an adverb. So it might be in some uses, but not here.

Comment: Would "in discussions in other disciplines" work?  It is what I would say.  Or "in discussion in unrelated disciplines / contexts" but I don't think there is a single word that would work exactly as you want (since you don't think elsewhere or other are sufficient)